# Number of $p$-local subgroups of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, normal-subgroups

A subgroup of a finite group is '$p$-local' if it is the normalizer of some Sylow $p$-subgroup. I want to prove that the number of $p$-local subgroups of a group is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$. I know that the index of a normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$ but how this is related with the statement? Any help would be great!

Comment: The usual definition of  $p$-local subgroup is the normalizer of any non-identity $p$-subgroup. With the definition you use, a hint for the fact you want is that all normalizers of Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate, and all such Sylow $p$-normalizers are self-normalizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate and the fact that $N_G(H^ {g})=N_G(H)^{g}$ for any subgroup $H$ of $G$ and $g \in G$. Let $P \in Syl_p(G)$. Then the number of $p$-local subgroups is the number of different conjugates of $N_G(P)$, which equals index$[G:N_G(N_G(P))]$. Now finally note (a well-known fact) that the $N_G(N_G(P))=N_G(P)$. Hence the number of local $p$-subgroups is index$]G:N_G(P)]$ and this is $\equiv 1$ mod $p$.

Comment: What do you mean by $N_{G}(H^{g})$?

Comment: For a subgroup $H\le G$, the notation $H^g$ denotes the conjugated subgroup $gHg^{-1}$.

Comment: @SameerKailasa I think it's actually $H^g = g^{-1} H g$ since it's supposed to be a right action with the exponential notation.

Comment: Sorry, I know the well known fact but I don't understand why the number of $p$-local subgroups is the number of different conjugates of $N_{G}(P)$.

Comment: Let $P$ be a fixed Sylow p subgroup.  Let $Q$ be any Sylow p subgroup.  As was pointed out $N_G(Q)=N_G(P^g)=(N_G(P))^g$ for some $g\in G$.  So the set of "p local subgroups" is the set of conjugates of $N_G(P)$.  Also for any subgroup K of G, the number of conjugates of K is the index of the normalizer of K in G.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I just realized that I have misunderstood the question so far, I thought that if a subgroup is p-local then it is a subgroup which normalize a Sylow p-subgroup so it is not necessarily equal to $N_{G}(P)$ for some Sylow p-subgroup $P$, it can be a proper subgroup contained in $N_{G}(P)$.Now it is very clear, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give another answer that is maybe easier. Let $\mathscr{N}=\{N_G(P):P \in Syl_p(G)\}$. Define a map $\phi: Syl_p(G) \rightarrow \mathscr{N}$ by $\phi(P)=N_G(P)$. Then surely $\phi$ is surjective. But it is also injective: suppose $\phi(P)=\phi(Q)$, so $N_G(P)=N_G(Q)$. Hence $Q \subseteq N_G(P)$ and $Q$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, so of $N_G(P)$. But $P$ is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$ and it follows that $P=Q$. Hence $\phi$ is bijective and $\#\mathscr{N}=\# Syl_p(G)$.